# sklearn clustering with custom metric: pairwise_distances throwing error

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I would like to cluster sets of spatial data using my own metric. The data comes as pairs of `(x,y)` values in a dataframe, where each set of pairs has an `id`. Like in the following example where I have three sets of points:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1] * 4 + [2] * 5 + [3] * 3, 
                   'x': np.random.random(12),
                   'y': np.random.random(12)}) 
df['xy'] = df[['x','y']].apply(lambda row: [row['x'],row['y']], axis = 1)
```

Here is the distance function I would like to use:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import directed_hausdorff
def some_distance(u, v):
    return max(directed_hausdorff(u, v)[0], directed_hausdorff(v, u)[0])
```

This function computes the [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance), i.e. the distance between two subsets `u` and `v` of `n`-dimensional space. In my case, I would like to use this distance function to cluster subsets of the real plane. In the data above there are three such subsets (`id`s from 1 to 3) so the resulting distance matrix should be 3x3.

My idea for the clustering step was to use `sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering` with a precomputed metric, which in turn I want to compute with `sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances`.

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances
def to_np_array(col):
    return np.array(list(col.values))
X = df.groupby('id')['xy'].apply(to_np_array).as_matrix()
m = pairwise_distances(X, X, metric=some_distance)
```

However, the last line is giving me an error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

What does work fine, however, is calling `some_distance(X[1], X[2])`. 
My hunch is that `X` needs to be a different format for `pairwise_distances` to work. Any ideas on how to make this work, or how to compute the matrix myself so I can stick it into `sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering`?

The error stack is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-e34155622595> in <module>
     12 def some_distance(u, v):
     13     return max(directed_hausdorff(u, v)[0], directed_hausdorff(v, u)[0])
---> 14 m = pairwise_distances(X, X, metric=some_distance)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py in pairwise_distances(X, Y, metric, n_jobs, **kwds)
   1430         func = partial(distance.cdist, metric=metric, **kwds)
   1431 
-> 1432     return _parallel_pairwise(X, Y, func, n_jobs, **kwds)
   1433 
   1434 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py in _parallel_pairwise(X, Y, func, n_jobs, **kwds)
   1065 
   1066     if effective_n_jobs(n_jobs) == 1:
-> 1067         return func(X, Y, **kwds)
   1068 
   1069     # TODO: in some cases, backend='threading' may be appropriate

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py in _pairwise_callable(X, Y, metric, **kwds)
   1079     """Handle the callable case for pairwise_{distances,kernels}
   1080     """
-> 1081     X, Y = check_pairwise_arrays(X, Y)
   1082 
   1083     if X is Y:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py in check_pairwise_arrays(X, Y, precomputed, dtype)
    106     if Y is X or Y is None:
    107         X = Y = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr', dtype=dtype,
--> 108                             warn_on_dtype=warn_on_dtype, estimator=estimator)
    109     else:
    110         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr', dtype=dtype,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    525             try:
    526                 warnings.simplefilter('error', ComplexWarning)
--> 527                 array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)
    528             except ComplexWarning:
    529                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    536 
    537     """
--> 538     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    539 
    540 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: Does that error include a traceback?  Tell us about `X`.   `sklearn` and your `some_distance` probably expects numpy arrays, or objects that can be made into arrays with a simple call like `np.asarray(X)`.  I don't think it has special knowledge about `pandas` structures.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj. The same error happens when I change `X` to a `numpy.ndarray` using `as_matrix()`. I have included the error stack above. I am starting to suspect that ´pairwise_distances´ might not be able to deal with arrays that contain something more complex than points in real space (even if you pass in a distance function that would produce distances for these complex things).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.distance import directed_hausdorff
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1] * 4 + [2] * 5 + [3] * 3, 'x':
np.random.random(12), 'y': np.random.random(12)}) 
df['xy'] = df[['x','y']].apply(lambda row: [row['x'],row['y']], axis = 1)
df.groupby('id')['xy'].apply(to_np_array)


def some_distance(u, v):
    return max(directed_hausdorff(u, v)[0], directed_hausdorff(v, u)[0])


def to_np_array(col):
    return np.array(list(col.values))


X = df.groupby('id')['xy'].apply(to_np_array)
d = np.zeros((len(X),len(X)))

for i, u in enumerate(X):
    for j, v in list(enumerate(X))[i:]:
        d[i,j] = some_distance(u,v)
        d[j,i] = d[i,j]
```

And now when you print `d` you get this:

```
array([[0.        , 0.58928274, 0.40767213],
   [0.58928274, 0.        , 0.510095  ],
   [0.40767213, 0.510095  , 0.        ]])
```

And for clustering:

```
cluster = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=2, affinity='precomputed', linkage = 'average')
cluster.fit(d)
```

Comment: Just to clarify - Hausdorff is a set metric that operates on subsets of (in my case) two-dimensional real space. These subsets are passed in as arrays of varying length (`u` and `v` in the code above). In my example there are three sets ( `id`s from 1 to 3) so any distance matrix should be 3x3. As I mentioned above `some_distance(X[1], X[2])` works just fine so it is unclear to me why you would change the distance function, and why a 4x4 matrix as a result would make sense.

Comment: Documentation of `pairwise_distance` says that it takes input `X` which is of shape ` [n_samples_a, n_features] ` but you were feeding an series with each element being a matrix of features, likewise `metric` is a callable which it is called on each pair of instances (rows) , going by that your code wouldn't function as per your need. Instead, you could write a simple for loop as I did in the answer and compute the distance.

Comment: Thanks. For anyone who might come across this later - this is how you then  get the distance matrix into `sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering`: Just run `cluster = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=2, affinity='precomputed', linkage = 'average');  cluster.fit(d)`.

Comment: Btw I have added the distance matrix computation to take into account that it is symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you showed some of the variables.  Fortunately you gave enough code to run it.  For example the dataframe:

```
In [9]: df                                                                                                      
Out[9]: 
    id         x         y                                          xy
0    1  0.428437  0.267264   [0.42843730501201727, 0.2672637429997736]
1    1  0.944687  0.023323  [0.9446872371859233, 0.023322969159167317]
2    1  0.091055  0.683154   [0.09105472832178496, 0.6831542985617349]
3    1  0.474522  0.313541    [0.4745222021519122, 0.3135405569298565]
4    2  0.835237  0.491541    [0.8352366339973815, 0.4915408434083248]
5    2  0.905918  0.854030    [0.9059178939221513, 0.8540297797160584]
6    2  0.182154  0.909656   [0.18215390836391654, 0.9096555360282939]
7    2  0.225270  0.522193   [0.22527013482912195, 0.5221926076838651]
8    2  0.924208  0.858627    [0.9242076604008371, 0.8586274362498842]
9    3  0.419813  0.634741   [0.41981292371175905, 0.6347409684931891]
10   3  0.954141  0.795452    [0.9541413559045294, 0.7954524369652217]
11   3  0.896593  0.271187    [0.8965932351250882, 0.2711872631673109]
```

And your `X`:

```
In [10]: X                                                                                                      
Out[10]: 
array([array([[0.42843731, 0.26726374],
       [0.94468724, 0.02332297],
       [0.09105473, 0.6831543 ],
       [0.4745222 , 0.31354056]]),
       array([[0.83523663, 0.49154084],
       [0.90591789, 0.85402978],
       [0.18215391, 0.90965554],
       [0.22527013, 0.52219261],
       [0.92420766, 0.85862744]]),
       array([[0.41981292, 0.63474097],
       [0.95414136, 0.79545244],
       [0.89659324, 0.27118726]])], dtype=object)
```

That is a (3,) object array - in effect a list of 3 2d arrays, with different sizes ((3,2),(5,2),(4,2)).   That's one array for each group.

How is `pairwise` supposed to feed that to your distance code?  `pairwise` docs says `X` should be a `(n,m)` array - n samples, m features.  Your `X` doesn't fit that description!

The error is probably produced by when trying to make a float array from `X`:

```
In [12]: np.asarray(X,dtype=float)                                                                              
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-a6e08bb1590c> in <module>
----> 1 np.asarray(X,dtype=float)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    536 
    537     """
--> 538     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    539 
    540 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: Thanks. To clarify - so `X` needs to be a `(n,m)` array of floats? Or could it also be a `(n,1)` array of `some_other_object` and then I pass in a distance_function that can compute distances of `some_other_object`s?